# Python time.sleep lock process

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-sleep

I want to create multi process app. Here is sample:

```
import threading
import time
from logs import LOG


def start_first():
    LOG.log("First thread has started")
    time.sleep(1000)


def start_second():
    LOG.log("second thread has started")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ### call birhtday daemon
    first_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_first())

    ### call billing daemon
    second_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_second())

    ### starting all daemons
    first_thread.start()
    second_thread.start()
```

In this code second thread does not work. I guess, after calling sleep function inside `first_thread` main process is slept. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92928/time-sleep-sleeps-thread-or-process). But here sleep was used with class. I got that(*Process finished with exit code 0*
) as a result when I run answer. Could anybody explain me where I made a mistake ?

- I am using python 3.* on windows

Comment: it actually would run but your `time.sleep(1000)` in method 1 is so long that you have to wait for 1000 seconds, change it to `time.sleep(5)` to see the immediate results.

Comment: OK, but it blocks second thread. Why it works like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating your thread you are actually invoking the functions when trying to set the target for the `Thread` instead of passing a function to it.  This means when you try to create the `first_thread` you are actually calling `start_first` which includes the very long sleep.  I imagine you then get frustrated that you don't see the output from the second thread and kill it, right?

Remove the parens from your `target=` statements and you will get what you want

```
first_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_first)
second_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_second)
first_thread.start()
second_thread.start()
```

will do what you are trying

Comment: Also, if you want to create a thread for a function with parameters you can use `first_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_first, args = ())`