# Sleep in async application, without blocking event loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, sleep, pytest

I have a problem with one my async tests: tornado seems not to be up and running (I get 599s), even though it is started as a fixture. I would like to verify that it is indeed running, by doing the following:

1. Start the test
2. Before the requests are actually sent to tornado, I would like my code to "sleep" for a long time so that I can manually check with the browser that tornado is indeed running.

How can I tell python to sleep without blocking the async loop? If I do `time.sleep`, the whole process (and thus the loop) is not responsive for the duration of the sleep.

Comment: `time.sleep()` is [supposed to suspend only the current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92928/time-sleep-sleeps-thread-or-process). Can you provide some code, so that we better understand the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your questions are answered in Tornado's FAQ:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/faq.html

Use `yield gen.sleep(1)` to wait 1 second while letting other tasks run on the event loop, or use `IOLoop.current().add_timeout(1, callback)` to run a callback one second later.

Don't use your browser to verify that your application handles multiple requests concurrently: the browser itself may not allow concurrent requests. Use `curl` instead.

Comment: Thanks. The browser was not supposed to be used as multiple requests tester, just as a manual check on whether the server was really started or not. It turned out to be a problem with several ioloops being implicitly defined, while only one was being started by the test framework (py.test). So, it really was a problem with the server not being up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You may check your code whether your request method is `POST` or `PUT`, I get the `599` Response Code when I use method `POST` and didn't post a data, and it gones when I added `data`.

`error:`

`res = self.fetch('/', method='POST')`

`fixed:`

`res = self.fetch('/', method='POST', data={})`