# what is the similar of task.delay of c# in python?

Tags: c#, python, multithreading

In c# we can do something like task.delay(t), stoping the execution of the current thread without blocking it, and allowing that thread to do other stuff until pass time t. So, my question is: what is the way to do this in python?

Comment: `time.sleep(t)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [time.sleep -- sleeps thread or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92928/time-sleep-sleeps-thread-or-process)

Answer (score 1):

the async "awaitable" sleep func is [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) (see the example provided there).

(as opposed to `time.sleep` which is just a regular sleep like C#'s Thread.Sleep...)

Comment: Delay in C: delay function is used to suspend execution of a program for a particular time. The op wants to **stop** the execution of the program

Comment: @Barb in C# Task.Delay is awaitable, hence OPs request for "stopping execution without blocking it". The equivalent of which in python is exactly asyncio.sleep.