# Script to wait till a specified time

Tags: python, time, while-loop, wait

**Wait till Specified Time**

I need the best way to halt a program until the specified time is mentioned(in variable wait_time a tuple of hours, minutes, seconds). I had tried to use *while loop* for this. But is there a more efficient way for this such that it doesn't take much of the CPU. After waiting it does a function called solve().

```py
wait_time=(12,10,15)
import time
time_str=time.localtime()
current_time=(time_str.tm_hour,time_str.tm_min,time_str,time_str.tm_sec)
while current_time!=wait_time:
    current_time=(time_str.tm_hour,time_str.tm_min,time_str,time_str.tm_sec)
else:
    print('Wait time over')
    solve()
```

I require a more efficient way than this for the memory part. It should wait until the system time is the time given.

Comment: Have you tried using sleep method??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [time.sleep -- sleeps thread or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92928/time-sleep-sleeps-thread-or-process)

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hacked together a method that should work for you:

> timeWait.py

```
import time

def waitTime(hrs, mins, secs):
    totalTime = ((hrs * 3600) + (mins * 60) + secs) # this is the time to wait in seconds
    time.sleep(totalTime) # time.sleep() sleeps for a given number of seconds
```

> Using it in the shell:

```
Python 3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeWait 
>>> timeWait.waitTime(1, 23, 42)
# This will wait/sleep for 1 hour, 23 minutes, and 42 seconds.
```

> How you can use it in your program:

```
import time

def waitTime(hrs, mins, secs):
    totalTime = ((hrs * 3600) + (mins * 60) + secs)
    time.sleep(totalTime)

waitTime(12, 10, 15)
# The following code will run when the time is up
print('Wait time over')
solve()
```

Comment: _`waitTime`_ sinful.

Comment: @AMC How so? Would you prefer ugly `wait_time`?

Comment: Ugly? Leave `snake_case` alone D:

Comment: `snake_case` is bad stuff. Everyone knows the _real_ pros use `camelCase`. Snake case is ugly, unprofessional, and hard to read.

Comment: I just wanted to bring up Python style conventions.

Comment: Well, write your code whichever way makes you feel good. _I_ personally find snake case to be new age and ugly. But that's just me. ^_^

Comment: _Well, write your code whichever way makes you feel good._ Nice strawman, everyone knows conventions and standards are worthless... That’s a doubly amusing attitude coming from someone who claims to be into macs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207480/discussion-between-noah-broyles-and-amc).