# Is there a way that i can pause a function but not effect other functions in Python?

Tags: python, discord

So basically i am coding a discord bot in python. It is a bot where you can buy/sell things from a shop, and go out farming or mining for resources. The main bit i need help with is making the function rest for around 5 minutes. This bot will probably be used multiple times in 5 minutes, so i can't pause the whole code. obviously time.sleep will not work since it pauses the whole script. I have tried a few different things but they didn't work well and i couldn't find much else on the internet. My code is:

```
    @client.command()
async def farm(ctx, item):
    fakelocation = 11
    await get_bank_data()
    users = await get_bank_data()
    if users[str(ctx.author.id)]["location"] == "Farm":
        item = item.lower()
        returnholder = 6
        product = "none"
        user = ctx.author
        users = await get_bank_data()
        if item == "potato":
            product = "potato"
            amount = random.randrange(2, 10)
            await ctx.send("Your crops will be given to you at the end of the session!")
            returnholder = 5
        if item == "carrot":
            product = "carrot"
            amount = random.randrange(4, 12)
            await ctx.send("Your crops will be given to you at the end of the session!")
            returnholder = 5
        if item == "wheat":
            product = "wheat"
            amount = random.randrange(7, 15)
            await ctx.send("Your crops will be given to you at the end of the session!")
            returnholder = 5
        if item == "apple":
            product = "apple"
            amount = random.randrange(2, 13)
            await ctx.send("Your crops will be given to you at the end of the session!")
            returnholder = 5
        if item == "banana":
            product = "banana"
            amount = random.randrange(4, 10)
            await ctx.send("Your crops will be given to you at the end of the session!")
            returnholder = 5
        if item == "orange":
            product = "orange"
            amount = random.randrange(3, 8)
            await ctx.send("Your crops will be given to you at the end of the session!")
            returnholder = 5
        if returnholder == 6:
            await ctx.send("That crop does not exist here!")
            return
        try:
            index = 0
            t = None
            for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
                n = thing["item"]
                if n == item:
                    old_amt = thing["amount"]
                    new_amt = old_amt + amount
                    users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                    t = 1
                    break
                index += 1
            if t == None:
                obj = {"item": product, "amount": amount}
                users[str(user.id)]["bag"].append(obj)
        except:
            obj = {"item": product, "amount": amount}
            users[str(user.id)]["bag"] = [obj]
        with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        fakelocation = 4
    if fakelocation == 11:
        await ctx.send("Please move to the Farm to farm!")
        return
```

This is the code and it is relatively similar to the Mine function. it checks what the item is and then if it exists it will give you a random amount of items.I want to make it stop first thing in `try:` since otherwise it will give you the items before the time is up. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92928/time-sleep-sleeps-thread-or-process

Comment: previous comment is a lot of help. but the concept is that You thread the process and in the definition of that process put in the time to sleep

Comment: @Matiiss How can i thread this process and make it work? sorry i am quite new to Python and i do not understand some of this complex stuff that i am looking at.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You have to include multiple threads in your program. Be aware that threading is an advanced topic.

Comment: He's already using async. @ACKtbt do `import asyncio; await asyncio.sleep(SECONDS)` It is asynchron and does not halt your entire program.

Comment: I suggest You take a look at some tutorials: I recommend this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso or a similar one about threading (also from Corey Schafer)

Comment: Yes thanks @TinNguyen that worked for me.

Comment: "making the function rest for around 5 minutes." What does this actually mean? Are you trying to delay the response when the command is used? Or implement a restriction on using the command frequently? In the latter case, if someone tries to use the command before the 5 minutes have elapsed, what should happen? An error message? Silently ignoring it? Remembering the command and running it later? Something else?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel what i want to do is make a function where you farm or mine, and after 5 minutes is up you get the resources in your bag (which is stored in a json file) without putting the whole code to sleep. I have already added a cooldown so you cant do it multiple times in that 5 minutes since that would then make it almost useless making it sleep. Tin Nguyen gave me a simple answer that worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
import asyncio

await asyncio.sleep(SECONDS)
```

This was the answer for me. Thanks @TinNguyen for answering my question simply.